# What happens if one manipulates non-exist key-value pair in a std::map?

Tags: c++

Say we have a std::map, declared as:

```
std::map<int, int> m;
```

Then, we immediately do this:

```
m[0]++;
```

What happens? According to my little experiment, m[0] goes to '1', as if there had been a '0' stored for key '0'.

But what if the map contains, say, custom types?

```
std::map<E, T> m;
m[e].function();
```

Would this work?

Actually I was wondering how C++ standard specifies this:)

Comment: Try it with the custom types and see :)

Comment: @Dgrin91 Sure I could but it was not likely possible for me to exhaust all possible situations. Especially, I would not like to come to a wrong conclusion from my particularly designed special test cases:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the overloaded `operator[]` for `std::map` actually **[creates](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator%5b%5d/)** the element passed as the argument, so by doing `m[0]++` you insert an `int` and do `++` on it. Nothing wrong with it being `1`

> A call to this function is equivalent to:
>   `(*((this->insert(make_pair(k,mapped_type()))).first)).second`

Comment: Illustrative! However I was still wondering, since your code suggests that a default constructor will be called to create the object to be inserted, which further implies that this object will no longer exist once our code goes beyond the scope it is created. Isn't that dangerous? Or is it true that std::map internally holds a safe copy of  what we pass to it by calling the Type's copy-constructor? But if this is the case, then what if a copy-constructor is unavailable (say being private)?

Comment: @Diaz the constructor is called withing the scope of the overloaded `operator[]`. If you wish to further dwell into the mechanics of the `map` container - why not just check it yourself? Since it's a template, the code should be available to you if you search in your compilers include directory. By the way - the code in my answer is taken from the link I've provided :)

Answer (score 1):

The `std::map` will introduce an "empty" element when you use the `operator[]` to access an entry.

If you don't want there to be an empty element, then you need to use `std::map::find()` to check if the element is there, and if it's not, don't use it.

Of course, as long as your type `T` is fine to have `function()` called on it, nothing bad will happen from `m[e].function()`. If `T` needs to be initialized with something useful before `function()` can be called, you'll have to make sure this doesn't happen.

Comment: What exactly is an "empty" element?

Comment: One created by the default constructor, `T()` (as opposed to a constructor that takes an argument, `T(x)` or `T(x, y, z)` for example).